# Browse webpages

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to simulate a user browsing webpages to create some actual user-stress on a network. I started with creating a browser intent, and then just used that to browse. While this worked, it would open a new tab in the default browser everytime a new webpage is launched.

My next option was to use a webview, but it seems it has some problems loading some pages. Lastly I tried using custom tabs - this worked fine, and could load all pages. But when I launch a new URL, it creates a new tab above the old one, not just changing the URL, and it seems it is not possible to close a custom tab.

Does anyone know a way for me to browse a list of websites, without opening new tabs everytime?

Comment: If your goal is to generate load on a web server, why are you doing this in Android? There are lots of tools available to do this from a normal PC.

Comment: @Henry, correct. We would like to use devices as close to the real world, so we have both computers and android devices. And it's not the webserver we're trying to load, it's the local gateway :)